# WP Query posts but order by User Meta Value

Tags: wordpress

I've looked for hours to see if this has been done before but haven't been able to find anything.

I have a WP Query that gets custom post types. This works fine, however I need to hook into this in order to change the order of the posts to be by meta_value but from the post author's user_meta.

The meta_key associated to the user is 'jobs_ordering' and the value is numeric (0 should show their posts first, 1 after etc).

So I need to order the posts by the meta_value from the user_meta key 'jobs_ordering'.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Thanks, I know how to query posts with standard ordering by meta_value however my question is to order by meta_value from the post_author's user_meta table instead, not the post_meta table....

Comment: Ah, sorry. Maybe this can help, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147407/how-to-order-posts-in-wp-query-by-a-meta-value-of-the-corresponding-author

Comment: Yeh, kind of...however I need to have the ordering/joining adding via a  hook (like posts_join, posts_orderby) rather than amending the args as that's part of a plugin and the code is horrendous too

Comment: Well you could call WP_User_Query and gather the ordered user ids in an array inside a hook as well I suppose?

Comment: Ok, I think I have a plan. When the user_meta value gets updated in the admin, I then add that value to all of their posts...